# Table query where field equal to query result in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm having some trouble translating this mysql query to an Laravel table query:

```
SELECT card
FROM card_groups
WHERE group_number = (
    SELECT group_number FROM card_groups WHERE card = '1111'
) AND card <> '1111';
```

That is: I want to obtain all card numbers that belong to the same group as '1111' except for '1111'. This is my Laravel query so far:

```
DB::table ('card_groups')->where ('group_number', /* SELECT GROUP ID IN SUB QUERY */)
                         ->where ('card', '<>', '1111');
```

Any idea? Thanks

**UPDATE**
I've rewritten my query using joins as follows:

```
SELECT cg.card
FROM card_groups cg
JOIN card_groups cg2 ON cg2.group_number = cg.group_number
WHERE cg2.card = '1111' AND cg.card <> '1111'
```

Comment: Check out Parameter Grouping here http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres.  I think this'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely need to use `whereRaw` for this one.

```
$query = DB::table('card_groups')
    ->select('card')
    ->where('card', '<>', $id);
$subQuery = DB::table('card_groups')
    ->select('group_number')
    ->where('card', '=', $id);
$query->whereRaw('group_number = '.$subQuery->toSql(), $subQuery->getBindings());
return $query->get();
```

Also in a broader perspective, I'm sure this can be rewritten to use joins which are probably more effective.

Comment: thanks Andreas, I've rewritten my query as suggested using joins